# MySQL - Как объединить две таблицы без дубликатов?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

У меня есть две таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно обеденить эти таблицы и выводить так чтобы получился

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда я вывожу их с помощю кода

```sql
SELECT * FROM comment
RIGHT JOIN comment_answer ON comment.ID = comment_answer.id_comments
ORDER BY comment.id DESC
```

у меня получаеться вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это уже на клиенте так вывод сформируй, а из БД сейчас все приходит как надо.

Comment: а как можно это реализовать?